# What tags are available to employers on Careers?

Tags: support, tags, jobs

What tags are available for employers on Careers?

Inspired by [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121465/why-are-part-time-jobs-in-programming-an-anomaly), I tried to find out how many part time jobs were available through Careers, but it seems there were none tagged part-time. When I went looking for the tags, I could only find the ones for employee profiles.

Answer (score 4):

Tags used by employers are meant to be technologies they use at the company.  When you do a search on Careers, we do have a selection for "Permanent" OR "Contract".

[image: Permanent or Contract]

We don't see a lot of demand from companies for part time employees, but more often contract workers.  This doesn't mean some of the permanent listings wouldn't consider part time employees, we just don't have a way for them to expose that in a structured way.